# how to read from text in a style of dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to make a program that reads info from text (dictionary). If key does not exist, program should add this key and keyvalue also must be added to the text file line by line. I did something but in reading part, there is problem saying list index out of range. Can anyone help ?

```
with open('text.txt','r') as file:
    x={}
    for line in file:
        key = line.rstrip().split(':')[0]
        keyvalue = line.rstrip().split(':')[1]
        x[key]=keyvalue
while True:
    name = input('whose hobby you wanna learn?:')
    if name in x:
        print('Name found')
        print("%s's hobby is %s" %(name,x[name]))
    else:
        print('i do not know',name)
        answer = input('do you wanna add this person?(yes or no)')
        if answer == ('yes'):
            new_user= input('type the name of new person:')
            new_user_hobby = input('type the hobby of that person:')
            x[new_user] = new_user_hobby
            with open('text.txt','a') as file:
                file.write('\n')
                file.write(new_user)
                file.write(':')
                file.write(new_user_hobby)
            print('person created successfully!')
```

Comment: Some line might not have a `:` character causing the split to only return a list of length 1.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat every line has i checked but of course there are empty lines

Comment: Which line of code throws this exception? Also, see [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: @jarmod 5. line (keyvalue = line.rstrip........) okay

Comment: @donutwithorange As a tip look into the `json` module in python. :)

Comment: @donutwithorange i strongly recommend you to use json, which deals with newlines etc., I made an answer with an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use JSON.

#### File data.json

```json
{
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2"
}
```

#### File main.py

```py
import json

with open("data.json", "r") as jsonfile:
    data = json.load(jsonfile)
    key = input("enter key: ")
    if key in data:
        print("key %s has value %s" % (key, data[key]))
    else:        
        add = input("key %s was not found in the data; do you want to add it ? " % key)
        if add:
            value = input("enter value for key %s : " % key)
            data[key] = value
    jsonfile.close()
    with open("data.json", "w") as jsonfile:
        json.dump(jsonfile, data)
```

If you run it, enter `key3`, then enter `yes`, then `value3`, and the `data.json` file will be like this:

```json
{
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2",
    "key3": "value3"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to change these lines

```py
key = line.rstrip().split(':')[0]
keyvalue = line.rstrip().split(':')[1]
```

to

```py
key, keyvalue = line.strip().split(':')
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have empty lines or lines not having `:`.
Try using if-else for this purpose:

```
with open('text.txt','r') as file:
    x={}
    for line in file:
        split_line = line.rstrip().split(':')
        if len(split_line) == 2:
            key = split_line[0]
            keyvalue = split_line[1]
            x[key]=keyvalue
```

Comment: This may work, but you should tell him to use the json module.